# Access control for required init

Tags: swift, access-control, initializer

The rule for access control for required initializer seems to be different than one that does not specify required. Why?

```
public class A {
  // required init() must be public, why?
  public required init() { }
}

public class B {
  // init() does not need to be public, why?
  init() { }
}
```

Comment: It's important to note here that this is only the case because the class itself is marked `public`.  If the class itself did not have an access modifier and presumed the default `internal`, your `required` initializer would also not require an access modifier.

Comment: @nhgrif look at the bold text in my answer. The required init would still need an access modifier that is at least `internal`, that is the default and therefore we can omit it.

Comment: I don't think my comment and your answer are in disagreement, @RMenke

Comment: @nhgrif just wanted to clarify, not correct ;)

Answer (score 2):

First, let's make the rule clear.  It is not required for `required` initializers to be marked as `public`.  It is only required that `required` initializers be as accessible as the class is.  If your class is `public`, it's required initializers must also be `public`.  If your class is `internal`, its required initializers must also be `internal` (technically, you could make it `public`, but that'd make no sense and generates a *warning*).  And of course, if your class is `private`, the required initializer should also be `private`.

---

#### So, why?

There are two reasons here, but they require an understanding of what the `required` keyword is actually doing.

---

First of all, the `required` keyword is guaranteeing this class and all of its subclasses implement this particular initializer.  One of the main reasons to make an initializer required is for protocol conformance, with the most popular example of this being `NSCoding`, which **requires** the `init(coder:)` initializer.  So with that in mind, let's consider a class which is trying to implement this protocol:

```
public class MySwiftClass: NSObject, NSCoding {
    // some implementations
    // including the two requirements of the NSCoding protocol
}
```

Now, consider trying to use this:

```
let mySwiftObject = MySwiftClass(coder: aCoder)
```

We should be able to do this without problem, right?  I mean, after all, `MySwiftClass` conforms to `NSCoding` protocol, and `NSCoding` protocol guarantees there will be an `init(coder:)` initializer.

But if you were allowed to mark `init(coder:)` as a lower access level than the class had, there would be a scope within which the class can be seen, but its required initializer could not be accessed... so despite knowing that this class conforms to a protocol with a required initializer or is inherited from a parent class with a required initializer, we'd somehow not be able to call that required initializer because for the scope we are in, it would appear to not exist.

---

The second reason is for subclassing itself.

Let's take this example parent class:

```
public class ParentClass {
    required init() {}
}
```

We want the zero-argument initializer to be required.  That means, if anything inherits from `ParentClass`, it must also be sure that the zero-argument initializer is implemented.  But if we are allowed to let the required initializer to have a lesser scope than the class itself, then there is a scope within which we can see the class, but we cannot see the required initializer, so how can subclasses created in that scope manage to even know there is a required initializer that they must implement?

Comment: I've been downvoted.  If someone would care to explain the mistake I've made, or how my answer can be improved, I'd love to update the answer.

Comment: Wasn't me, and it looks fine to me. But then again I messed up my own answer after the million edits. I am close to giving up on this Q/A. This issue is definitely not worth getting downvotes.

Comment: Not me either.  SO should really improve this aspect.